# java command works but javac command doesn't?

Tags: java

I have downloaded the jdk 1.8.0_131

when I open the command prompt and write the following command - java -version it gives me the output

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

but when I write the following command: javac -version it gives me the output

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have edit the system variables path to - C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;

and when I do the following command : "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac" -version

it gives me the output:

```
javac 1.8.0_131
```

So i know I have installed the correct java version

I also checked the above folder and did find a javac.exe there. Please help.

Edit:

I finally solved the problem. What I was doing is editing the "Path" variable when what I had to do was make a new variable called "PATH" and the the following details :

```
Variable name  : PATH
Variable value : c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx\bin;[Existing Entries...
```

Comment: You probably have not declared the `CLASSPATH` variable. Refer this [link](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html)

Comment: Hope you have reopened the bash and tried this. Because the changes in path setting affect only in newly opened bash/shell

Comment: Gandalf: that is nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting "cmd.exe" since adding the bin directory to your PATH?

If you confirm that your PATH includes the java bin directory and you can see the "javac.exe" binary in that location, then all should be set up correctly.

Comment: I think my path is right. when i do the command echo %PATH% I get the output - "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;";C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath; and so on

Comment: @UtkarshSharma If you do `dir C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\*.exe` does it list `javac.exe`?

Comment: Yeah it gives javac.exe:  11/06/2017  10:56 PM            15,904 javac.exe

Comment: @UtkarshSharma Not sure if you pasted that `PATH` correctly, because there should be no `"` characters in it, so that could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you need to add path to the `jdk_your_version/bin` to the `PATH` variable. Add this line to the `PATH`:

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;
```

Save it. Then restart `CMD` since it does not update the path automatically for the open cmd. Then you should be able to see that `javac` is working:

```
javac -version
```